# Need Help Loading Plist Into Multiple Tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, plist

I have successfully loaded the muscleName items into a table view but am not having any luck loading their respective exerciseName into the 2nd table view.

The method I am using is:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"exerciseName"];
```

Maybe I need to define constants?

[image]

Edit:

Here is the code in ViewDidLoad for the first table that loads muscleName:

```
if (muscleArray == nil)
{
    //Read the plist file into an array (the root element is an array)
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.muscleArray = rootLevel;
    [rootLevel release];
```

Here is my current sub table class

```
 import "SpecificExerciseTableViewController.h"
    #import "MusclesTableViewController.h"
    #import "CurlAppDelegate.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @implementation SpecificExerciseTableViewController
    @synthesize exerciseArray;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [exerciseArray release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Exercises";

        [super viewDidLoad];

        if (exerciseArray == nil)
        {
            //Read the plist file into an array (the root element is an array)
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
            NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            self.exerciseArray = rootLevel;
            [rootLevel release];
        }

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.exerciseArray count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];

        return cell;

    }

    - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tv accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

         DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];

    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it looks like you're accessing the `exerciseName` property okay if you are starting at `exercises`.
Are you sure that `self.exerciseArray` is pointing to your `exercises` object? The quickest way to check is just drop in an `NSLog()` statement and see if you have what you think you have:

```
NSLog(@"Exercises: %@", self.exerciseArray);
```

Comment: I added the code in the viewDidLoad for the first table in the edit above.

Comment: @Faisal: when a row is tapped in the first view, you can get the dictionary that is at row's index in the root array. The `exercises` array is inside that dictionary. `[[muscleArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"exercises"]` Is this what you are doing?

Comment: I'm getting muscleArray undeclared for ExerciseViewController even though I imported muscleTableViewController and referenced the class.

Comment: hmm i've tied a bunch of stuff but nothing is really working for the 2nd table (exercise table)